# Slow scrolling on TextView of AlertDialog when using setView

Tags: android, textview, android-alertdialog, clickable

### Background

I wish to add the ability to click on links inside the TextView that is shown on the alertDialog.

### The problem

It all shows well and the links are clickable.

However, the scrolling is very slow and doesn't allow the fast scrolling gesture (flick? swipe up?).

Also, the scroller itself has become invisible.

### What I've tried

This is the code I use:

```
  public static void showWhatsNewDialog(final Activity activity)
    {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.whats_new);
    final TextView textView=new TextView(activity);
    textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,18);
    builder.setView(textView);
    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(...));
    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    textView.setClickable(true);
    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,null);
    builder.show();
    }
```

### The question

Is there a better way to achieve this, that will get the scrolling issue being fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create a class which extends `Dialog` and create a layout you want to show in alert dialog, and set this `Layout` to your CustomDialog class.create a layout like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

  <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

  <ScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/message"
    />
  </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and set this layout to your CustomDialog class.

Comment: Going this far for a clickable textView ? Are you sure there is no other way?

Comment: for scrolling issue you can add a `TextViwe` inside a `ScrollView`, add clickListener on `TextView` And I don't thing there is any batter way to do this.

Comment: clickListener will work for the entire view, instead of simple links within it. Also, I think that using "setView" already puts the view in a scrollView. I need to check it out.

Comment: for adding hyperlink in test view use `<a href > </a>` tag to define string in `string` file, instead of adding clickListener.

Comment: This is what I did , and you forgot the part of "Html.fromHtml" and "setMovementMethod" , otherwise it won't work

Comment: I know you have used `"Html.fromHtml`. I just suggest you to do things using custom `Alert dialog` instead adding view in `AlertDialog.Builder`.

Comment: OK, using a scrollview (which holds the textView) for the "setView" parameter worked. Only thing I added is to also call "setFillViewport(true)" . Can you please modify your answer to show this code, so that I could tick it as the correct answer?

Comment: @androiddeveloper I have added layout code you can now accept this as Ans.

Comment: This is not the answer I was talking about. I still used "setView" on the normal AlertDialog. I just set the parameter to be a Scrollview with a TextView inside of it. Not need for a customized class.